# Equivalent of Partial<T> for instance methods?

Tags: typescript

I know how to use `Partial` to make the properties optional:

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: (arg: any) => void;
}

type PartialFoo = Partial<Foo>;
// results in:
// {
//   foo?: (arg: any) => void;
// }
```

However, I want to do the same thing for instance methods rather than properties:

```js
interface Foo {
  foo(arg: any): void;
}

type PartialFoo = Partial<Foo>;
// results in:
// {
//   foo?: (arg: any) => void;
// }

// but I want:
// {
//   foo?(arg: any): void;
// }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is a small difference between methods and function-valued properties in the type system, but you are allowed to implement either as the other.  Can you show something that actually goes wrong if you use the `PartialFoo` type above?

Comment: I am using Angular, and if I define lifecycle hooks as properties then they don't get called (e.g. defining `ngOnInit = () => { ...}` in a component doesn't work). I am writing code related to mixins, which is why I want to manipulate types corresponding to these methods.

Comment: It sounds like you think having `PartialFoo["foo"]` be represented as function-valued property in the type system somehow means you have to *implement* it as a property.  But you don't.  See [this](https://tsplay.dev/DWKpKw).  Function-valued properties and methods are more or less mutually assignable.  (There are some wrinkles and the compiler doesn't treat them as *exactly* the same, but it doesn't look like you're talking about these issues.)

Comment: If `ngOnInit = () => { ...}` is _really_ not getting called by angular but `ngOnInit() { ...}` is I would say it's a bug in the framework.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz to demonstrate:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dn9bdd?file=src/app/mixin.ts this is all working correctly if I simply change the ngOnInit in the component to be an instance method. What I would like to do is not manually write out all of the `ngOnChanges` etc. in mixins.ts, but to instead use the angular interfaces such as `OnInit`

Comment: So you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27689)?  It would have been nice if your stackblitz was a [mcve] that actually showed an error message somewhere, since I've just spent a bunch of effort just to get to the part where an issue is demonstrated.

Comment: I'd say go to [microsoft/TypeScript#27689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27689) and give it a , and for now just use your annoying workaround of manually writing out the method types.  I'd make that an answer but I feel kind of done here.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes you are right that issue is the problem! Thanks for the help, and sorry yes I should have simplified my stackblitz example!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do mixins related to lifecycle methods in angular, I suggest to rather check if the component correctly implements the associated interfaces.

`ngOnInit` -> [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

`ngOnChanges` -> [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

...etc